# Print every tag in xml

Tags: php, xml, domdocument

I have this xml

[image]

I want to loop trough every tag in the node 'section' and print every tag name and text with in the tag.

With domdocument I load this as a xml object.

```
foreach ($maindoc->childNodes AS $item) {
    echo '11111111111';
    //var_dump(get_class($item));
    print $item->nodeName . " = " . $item->nodeValue . "<br/><br/>";
}
```

However I get just one big string back of all tags. All text within the tags are glued together and the tags are not printed.

**UPDATE 1**
I have inserted the xml. 
The recursve class only work for just one level. 
This script detele the tag for sublevels. 
I search fro a script which shows alle tags in the same order and level as the original xml

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<folder id="5" document-type-key="1_Default" documentTypeName="Default">
<naam>Test Default</naam>
<meta>
<thema/>
</meta>
<document id="23" document-type-key="1_Default" documentTypeName="Default" state="In Progress">
<naam>PublishOne Content Structure</naam>
<lastmodified>2018-08-29T12:32:31.9447088Z</lastmodified>
<meta>
<contentsoort>Eerste Waarde</contentsoort>
</meta>
<document version="1" track-changes="false">
<h1 class="heading_1" id="po-heading-id__ffea4N8nkylowkTQ0mn4A">The Project Folder Structure</h1>
<p>Items in PublishOne are organised in a fixed tree structure. At top level, you will have a number of Project Folders. Each of these Folders can contain a set of Project sub-Folders (or sub-Projects), Documents, Links, and Assets. This structure determines how content is handled during publication. The figure bellows shows an example of such a structure.</p>
<p>
<img id="Id58d750effd314d2c82aa6384d91b60da" height="255" width="453" href="https://bhp-em.publishone.nl/api/content/20"/>
</p>
<list format="%1." type="number">
<li>
<p>Project Folder</p>
</li>
<li>
<p>Content Link</p>
</li>
<li>
<p>Document</p>
</li>
<li>
<p>Asset</p>
</li>
<li>
<p>Project sub-Folder</p>
</li>
</list>
<h1 class="heading_1" id="po-heading-id_Q4ooBh9ixEGUeG1pXvcrpw">The Document Type</h1>
<p>PublishOne can be configured to manage the content in line with a desired process. In order to allow clients to manage various content sets with varying processes, content elements have an associated Document Type.</p>
<p>The Document Type determines:</p>
<list format="" type="bullet">
<li>
<p>The workflow process by which the Documents are managed, including more complex functions</p>
</li>
<li>
<p>The styling and other content specifics</p>
</li>
<li>
<p>The make-up of the PublishOne Ribbon</p>
</li>
<li>
<p>The client specific metadata for each of the four content elements (Document, Asset, Link, Folder)</p>
</li>
</list>
<h2 class="heading_2" id="po-heading-id_CWp4DpXNW0SN6gKfNnJk5w">Document Type Information</h2>
<p>The Document Type has the following attributes:</p>
<list format="" type="bullet">
<li>
<p>The Name as used in the user interface</p>
</li>
<li>
<p>The Icon as used in the user interface</p>
</li>
<li>
<p>The MS Word template used for editing in MS Word (through Document Template)</p>
</li>
<li>
<p>The initial content used for creating new documents (through Document Template)</p>
</li>
</list>
<p>
<img id="Idb1ccbac7e271481ba3c58f529378d56f" height="255" width="453" href="https://bhp-em.publishone.nl/api/content/19"/>
</p>
<list format="%1." type="number">
<li>
<p>The Document Type Name as visible on a Document card</p>
</li>
<li>
<p>The Document Type Icon as visible on a Document card</p>
</li>
</list>
<h2 class="heading_2" id="po-heading-id_ozvQ0FgiKUCNfU2UabkJDg">The Document Type Workflow</h2>
<p>A workflow in PublishOne exists of Workflow States and Workflow Transitions between these States. The Workflow controls the Documents in PublishOne. For each of the States, you can determine which Roles are allowed to edit the Document Content in the State. A Workflow State has the following attributes:</p>
<list format="" type="bullet">
<li>
<p>The Name as used in the user interface</p>
</li>
<li>
<p>The Order By number determining the natural order of the States</p>
</li>
<li>
<p>Ready for Production mark, indicating that Documents in this State can be published</p>
</li>
<li>
<p>The State Colour as used in the user interface</p>
</li>
<li>
<p>Edit Roles, the list of Roles that are allowed to edit the Document in this State</p>
</li>
</list>
<p>
<img id="Id015e81bccd654535bed69561bf8884cf" height="255" width="453" href="https://bhp-em.publishone.nl/api/content/18"/>
</p>
<list format="%1." type="number">
<li>
<p>The State Colour as visible on a Document card</p>
</li>
<li>
<p>The State Name as visible on a Document card</p>
</li>
<li>
<p>The User in their Roles has edit rights</p>
</li>
<li>
<p>The User in their Roles does not have edit rights</p>
</li>
</list>
<p>Workflow Transitions have the following attributes:</p>
<list format="" type="bullet">
<li>
<p>The From State, start point of the Transition</p>
</li>
<li>
<p>The To State, end point of the Transition</p>
</li>
<li>
<p>The user Role that can initiate the Transition</p>
</li>
<li>
<p>The Mail Template, to auto-generate mails to be issued to users that have a Role that can edit in the To State</p>
</li>
<li>
<p>The Order By number, for ordering in the user interface</p>
</li>
<li>
<p>Save Version mark (Backup document?) to have a versions stored during the Transition</p>
</li>
<li>
<p>Needs Validation mark, to auto-trigger validation and block Documents that do not validate from moving to the To State</p>
</li>
</list>
<p> The figure below represents a sample workflow as you could configure in PublishOne.</p>
<p>
<img id="Idcedd46ed23b243c7a345b97cdf8c1c96" height="255" width="453" href="https://bhp-em.publishone.nl/api/content/17"/>
</p>
<list format="%1." type="number">
<li>
<p>Edit rights, in this example the ‘Author’ can edit in the ‘Create’ State, the ‘Editor’ and ‘Publisher’ cannot</p>
</li>
<li>
<p>The Role ‘Author’ can hand in work from Workflow State ‘Create’ to ‘Edit’</p>
</li>
<li>
<p>The Role ‘Editor’ can request changes by moving back from ‘Edit’ to ‘Create’</p>
</li>
<li>
<p>The ‘Publish’ state is configured to allow publication (Ready for Production)</p>
</li>
</list>
<h2 class="heading_2" id="po-heading-id_rSxUEM7XF0idI6SfkhK9lA"> The Document Type Metadata</h2>
<p>For a Document Type, you can configure the Metadata for each of the four Item Types. In the below figure you see an example of Metadata sets for the Item Type Document and Project Folder within the same Document Type.</p>
<p>
<img id="Id2cf79d4a0905466d8ff897c5d45c53e8" height="255" width="453" href="https://bhp-em.publishone.nl/api/content/22"/>
</p>
<list format="%1." type="number">
<li>
<p>The Metadata configured for the Project Folders of a Document Type</p>
</li>
<li>
<p>The Metadata configured for the Documents of the same Document Type</p>
</li>
</list>
<h2 class="heading_2" id="po-heading-id_pulf5jFtHkaK438Bk_wlng">Users, Roles and Groups</h2>
<p>Users in PublishOne are represented by a name and an email address. A user can have multiple roles, although generally it is better to limit the amount of roles a user has, ideally just one.</p>
<p/>
<p>
Users are connected to the content through Assignments. As an example, a user with the role Author can be assigned to a Item in the role 
<span class="Value">Author</span>
, which means that on that Item the user has the rights associated with the role 
<span class="Value">Author</span>
. The following figure shows this example.
</p>
<p>
<img id="Id8df58c66dc03484296580a1c14876025" height="253" width="450" href="https://bhp-em.publishone.nl/api/content/21"/>
</p>
<list format="%1." type="number">
<li>
<p>
The tab 
<span class="View">Users</span>
is selected
</p>
</li>
<li>
<p>
For the document 
<span class="Value">PublishOne Content Structure</span>
</p>
</li>
<li>
<p>
The 
<span class="Value">Author</span>
assignment
</p>
</li>
<li>
<p>
The 
<span class="Value">Reader</span>
role is handed to a Group, to provide its members with read-only access
</p>
</li>
</list>
</section>
</document>
</document>
</folder>
```

```html
Tag: p Value: PublishOne Content Structure
Tag: h1 Value: User Interface Naming Convention
Tag: list Value: no value - Has 1 attributes
Tag: li Value: no value - Has 0 attributes
Tag: p Value: no value - Has 1 attributes
Tag: h1 Value: Content in PublishOne
Tag: p Value: PublishOne is designed to create, manage, and publish content. The main types by which the content in PublishOne is organized are:
Tag: list Value: Document – the element that contains the actual content text and its style taggingAsset – the element that contains and manages images, videos, and other graphical contentLinks (or Content Links) – the element that manages the inclusion of other elementsFolder (or Project) – the element used to organize the content
Tag: li Value: Document – the element that contains the actual content text and its style tagging
Tag: p Value: Document – the element that contains the actual content text and its style tagging
Tag: li Value: Asset – the element that contains and manages images, videos, and other graphical content
Tag: p Value: Asset – the element that contains and manages images, videos, and other graphical content
Tag: li Value: Links (or Content Links) – the element that manages the inclusion of other elements
Tag: p Value: Links (or Content Links) – the element that manages the inclusion of other elements
Tag: li Value: Folder (or Project) – the element used to organize the content
Tag: p Value: Folder (or Project) – the element used to organize the content
Tag: p Value: These are generally referred to as ‘Items’, with the Document, Asset, Link, and Project Folder being the four available ‘Item Types’.
Tag: p Value: Each Item has three sets of data stored:
Tag: list Value: Content – for example the text for a Document or images for an AssetMetadata – the standard metadata like Document Title plus the metadata as configured by your own organisationUsers – the users assigned to the content element
Tag: li Value: Content – for example the text for a Document or images for an Asset
Tag: p Value: Content – for example the text for a Document or images for an Asset
Tag: li Value: Metadata – the standard metadata like Document Title plus the metadata as configured by your own organisation
Tag: p Value: Metadata – the standard metadata like Document Title plus the metadata as configured by your own organisation
Tag: li Value: Users – the users assigned to the content element
Tag: p Value: Users – the users assigned to the content element
Tag: p Value: no value - Has 0 attributes
Tag: h1 Value: The Project Folder Structure
Tag: p Value: Items in PublishOne are organised in a fixed tree structure. At top level, you will have a number of Project Folders. Each of these Folders can contain a set of Project sub-Folders (or sub-Projects), Documents, Links, and Assets. This structure determines how content is handled during publication. The figure bellows shows an example of such a structure.
Tag: p Value: no value - Has 0 attributes
Tag: img Value: no value - Has 1 attributes
Tag: list Value: Project FolderContent LinkDocumentAssetProject sub-Folder
Tag: li Value: Project Folder
Tag: p Value: Project Folder
Tag: li Value: Content Link
Tag: p Value: Content Link
Tag: li Value: Document
Tag: p Value: Document
Tag: li Value: Asset
Tag: p Value: Asset
Tag: li Value: Project sub-Folder
Tag: p Value: Project sub-Folder
Tag: h1 Value: The Document Type
Tag: p Value: PublishOne can be configured to manage the content in line with a desired process. In order to allow clients to manage various content sets with varying processes, content elements have an associated Document Type.
Tag: p Value: The Document Type determines:
Tag: list Value: The workflow process by which the Documents are managed, including more complex functionsThe styling and other content specificsThe make-up of the PublishOne RibbonThe client specific metadata for each of the four content elements (Document, Asset, Link, Folder)
Tag: li Value: The workflow process by which the Documents are managed, including more complex functions
Tag: p Value: The workflow process by which the Documents are managed, including more complex functions
Tag: li Value: The styling and other content specifics
Tag: p Value: The styling and other content specifics
Tag: li Value: The make-up of the PublishOne Ribbon
Tag: p Value: The make-up of the PublishOne Ribbon
Tag: li Value: The client specific metadata for each of the four content elements (Document, Asset, Link, Folder)
Tag: p Value: The client specific metadata for each of the four content elements (Document, Asset, Link, Folder)
Tag: h2 Value: Document Type Information
Tag: p Value: The Document Type has the following attributes:
Tag: list Value: The Name as used in the user interfaceThe Icon as used in the user interfaceThe MS Word template used for editing in MS Word (through Document Template)The initial content used for creating new documents (through Document Template)
Tag: li Value: The Name as used in the user interface
Tag: p Value: The Name as used in the user interface
Tag: li Value: The Icon as used in the user interface
Tag: p Value: The Icon as used in the user interface
Tag: li Value: The MS Word template used for editing in MS Word (through Document Template)
Tag: p Value: The MS Word template used for editing in MS Word (through Document Template)
Tag: li Value: The initial content used for creating new documents (through Document Template)
Tag: p Value: The initial content used for creating new documents (through Document Template)
Tag: p Value: no value - Has 0 attributes
Tag: img Value: no value - Has 1 attributes
Tag: list Value: The Document Type Name as visible on a Document cardThe Document Type Icon as visible on a Document card
Tag: li Value: The Document Type Name as visible on a Document card
Tag: p Value: The Document Type Name as visible on a Document card
Tag: li Value: The Document Type Icon as visible on a Document card
Tag: p Value: The Document Type Icon as visible on a Document card
Tag: h2 Value: The Document Type Workflow
Tag: p Value: A workflow in PublishOne exists of Workflow States and Workflow Transitions between these States. The Workflow controls the Documents in PublishOne. For each of the States, you can determine which Roles are allowed to edit the Document Content in the State. A Workflow State has the following attributes:
Tag: list Value: The Name as used in the user interfaceThe Order By number determining the natural order of the StatesReady for Production mark, indicating that Documents in this State can be publishedThe State Colour as used in the user interfaceEdit Roles, the list of Roles that are allowed to edit the Document in this State
Tag: li Value: The Name as used in the user interface
Tag: p Value: The Name as used in the user interface
Tag: li Value: The Order By number determining the natural order of the States
Tag: p Value: The Order By number determining the natural order of the States
Tag: li Value: Ready for Production mark, indicating that Documents in this State can be published
Tag: p Value: Ready for Production mark, indicating that Documents in this State can be published
Tag: li Value: The State Colour as used in the user interface
Tag: p Value: The State Colour as used in the user interface
Tag: li Value: Edit Roles, the list of Roles that are allowed to edit the Document in this State
Tag: p Value: Edit Roles, the list of Roles that are allowed to edit the Document in this State
Tag: p Value: no value - Has 0 attributes
Tag: img Value: no value - Has 1 attributes
Tag: list Value: The State Colour as visible on a Document cardThe State Name as visible on a Document cardThe User in their Roles has edit rightsThe User in their Roles does not have edit rights
Tag: li Value: The State Colour as visible on a Document card
Tag: p Value: The State Colour as visible on a Document card
Tag: li Value: The State Name as visible on a Document card
Tag: p Value: The State Name as visible on a Document card
Tag: li Value: The User in their Roles has edit rights
Tag: p Value: The User in their Roles has edit rights
Tag: li Value: The User in their Roles does not have edit rights
Tag: p Value: The User in their Roles does not have edit rights
Tag: p Value: Workflow Transitions have the following attributes:
Tag: list Value: The From State, start point of the TransitionThe To State, end point of the TransitionThe user Role that can initiate the TransitionThe Mail Template, to auto-generate mails to be issued to users that have a Role that can edit in the To StateThe Order By number, for ordering in the user interfaceSave Version mark (Backup document?) to have a versions stored during the TransitionNeeds Validation mark, to auto-trigger validation and block Documents that do not validate from moving to the To State
Tag: li Value: The From State, start point of the Transition
Tag: p Value: The From State, start point of the Transition
Tag: li Value: The To State, end point of the Transition
Tag: p Value: The To State, end point of the Transition
Tag: li Value: The user Role that can initiate the Transition
Tag: p Value: The user Role that can initiate the Transition
Tag: li Value: The Mail Template, to auto-generate mails to be issued to users that have a Role that can edit in the To State
Tag: p Value: The Mail Template, to auto-generate mails to be issued to users that have a Role that can edit in the To State
Tag: li Value: The Order By number, for ordering in the user interface
Tag: p Value: The Order By number, for ordering in the user interface
Tag: li Value: Save Version mark (Backup document?) to have a versions stored during the Transition
Tag: p Value: Save Version mark (Backup document?) to have a versions stored during the Transition
Tag: li Value: Needs Validation mark, to auto-trigger validation and block Documents that do not validate from moving to the To State
Tag: p Value: Needs Validation mark, to auto-trigger validation and block Documents that do not validate from moving to the To State
Tag: p Value: The figure below represents a sample workflow as you could configure in PublishOne.
Tag: p Value: no value - Has 0 attributes
Tag: img Value: no value - Has 1 attributes
Tag: list Value: Edit rights, in this example the ‘Author’ can edit in the ‘Create’ State, the ‘Editor’ and ‘Publisher’ cannotThe Role ‘Author’ can hand in work from Workflow State ‘Create’ to ‘Edit’The Role ‘Editor’ can request changes by moving back from ‘Edit’ to ‘Create’The ‘Publish’ state is configured to allow publication (Ready for Production)
Tag: li Value: Edit rights, in this example the ‘Author’ can edit in the ‘Create’ State, the ‘Editor’ and ‘Publisher’ cannot
Tag: p Value: Edit rights, in this example the ‘Author’ can edit in the ‘Create’ State, the ‘Editor’ and ‘Publisher’ cannot
Tag: li Value: The Role ‘Author’ can hand in work from Workflow State ‘Create’ to ‘Edit’
Tag: p Value: The Role ‘Author’ can hand in work from Workflow State ‘Create’ to ‘Edit’
Tag: li Value: The Role ‘Editor’ can request changes by moving back from ‘Edit’ to ‘Create’
Tag: p Value: The Role ‘Editor’ can request changes by moving back from ‘Edit’ to ‘Create’
Tag: li Value: The ‘Publish’ state is configured to allow publication (Ready for Production)
Tag: p Value: The ‘Publish’ state is configured to allow publication (Ready for Production)
Tag: h2 Value: The Document Type Metadata
Tag: p Value: For a Document Type, you can configure the Metadata for each of the four Item Types. In the below figure you see an example of Metadata sets for the Item Type Document and Project Folder within the same Document Type.
Tag: p Value: no value - Has 0 attributes
Tag: img Value: no value - Has 1 attributes
Tag: list Value: The Metadata configured for the Project Folders of a Document TypeThe Metadata configured for the Documents of the same Document Type
Tag: li Value: The Metadata configured for the Project Folders of a Document Type
Tag: p Value: The Metadata configured for the Project Folders of a Document Type
Tag: li Value: The Metadata configured for the Documents of the same Document Type
Tag: p Value: The Metadata configured for the Documents of the same Document Type
Tag: h2 Value: Users, Roles and Groups
Tag: p Value: Users in PublishOne are represented by a name and an email address. A user can have multiple roles, although generally it is better to limit the amount of roles a user has, ideally just one.
Tag: p Value: no value - Has 0 attributes
Tag: p Value: Users are connected to the content through Assignments. As an example, a user with the role Author can be assigned to a Item in the role Author, which means that on that Item the user has the rights associated with the role Author. The following figure shows this example.
Tag: span Value: Author
Tag: span Value: Author
Tag: p Value: no value - Has 0 attributes
Tag: img Value: no value - Has 1 attributes
Tag: list Value: The tab Users is selectedFor the document PublishOne Content StructureThe Author assignmentThe Reader role is handed to a Group, to provide its members with read-only access
Tag: li Value: The tab Users is selected
Tag: p Value: The tab Users is selected
Tag: span Value: Users
Tag: li Value: For the document PublishOne Content Structure
Tag: p Value: For the document PublishOne Content Structure
Tag: span Value: PublishOne Content Structure
Tag: li Value: The Author assignment
Tag: p Value: The Author assignment
Tag: span Value: Author
Tag: li Value: The Reader role is handed to a Group, to provide its members with read-only access
Tag: p Value: The Reader role is handed to a Group, to provide its members with read-only access
Tag: span Value: Reader
```

Comment: Please include the XML as text directly into your question instead of an image. You should also include a complete XML document so people can test the code. It would also help if you included an example of the output you're currently getting and the output you're expecting. That would greatly help us to see what's going on.

Comment: That XML is not valid - there are parse errors when trying to process it with DOMDocument

Answer (score 1):

Without the XML file to work with the following is untested but might give an idea how you can iterate through the various collections. Using a simple RecursiveIterator and a [DOM iterator class](https://github.com/salathe/spl-examples/wiki/RecursiveDOMIterator) you can easily iterate through all the child nodes of either the entire document or a particular node within the document.

```
<?php
    class RecursiveDOMIterator implements RecursiveIterator {
        /*


            -----------------------------------------------------------------
            https://github.com/salathe/spl-examples/wiki/RecursiveDOMIterator
            -----------------------------------------------------------------


        */
        /**
         * Current Position in DOMNodeList
         * @var Integer
         */
        protected $_position;

        /**
         * The DOMNodeList with all children to iterate over
         * @var DOMNodeList
         */
        protected $_nodeList;

        /**
         * @param DOMNode $domNode
         * @return void
         */
        public function __construct(DOMNode $domNode)
        {
            $this->_position = 0;
            $this->_nodeList = $domNode->childNodes;
        }

        /**
         * Returns the current DOMNode
         * @return DOMNode
         */
        public function current()
        {
            return $this->_nodeList->item($this->_position);
        }

        /**
         * Returns an iterator for the current iterator entry
         * @return RecursiveDOMIterator
         */
        public function getChildren()
        {
            return new self($this->current());
        }

        /**
         * Returns if an iterator can be created for the current entry.
         * @return Boolean
         */
        public function hasChildren()
        {
            return $this->current()->hasChildNodes();
        }

        /**
         * Returns the current position
         * @return Integer
         */
        public function key()
        {
            return $this->_position;
        }

        /**
         * Moves the current position to the next element.
         * @return void
         */
        public function next()
        {
            $this->_position++;
        }

        /**
         * Rewind the Iterator to the first element
         * @return void
         */
        public function rewind()
        {
            $this->_position = 0;
        }

        /**
         * Checks if current position is valid
         * @return Boolean
         */
        public function valid()
        {
            return $this->_position < $this->_nodeList->length;
        }
    }




    $xmlfile='c:/wwwroot/xml/complexdata.xml';
    $tag='catalog_item';


    $dom=new DOMDocument;
    $dom->preserveWhiteSpace = false;
    $dom->load( $xmlfile );

    $items=$dom->getElementsByTagName( $tag );
    $item=$items->item(0);

    /*
        Alternatively - to process the entire document - pass $dom as the object to the DOM iterator class constructor
        $itr = new RecursiveIteratorIterator( new RecursiveDOMIterator( $dom ), RecursiveIteratorIterator::SELF_FIRST );
    */

    $itr = new RecursiveIteratorIterator( new RecursiveDOMIterator( $item ), RecursiveIteratorIterator::SELF_FIRST );
    foreach( $itr as $node ){
        if( $node->nodeType==XML_ELEMENT_NODE ) {

            $tagname=$node->tagName;
            $value=!empty( $node->nodeValue ) ? $node->nodeValue : sprintf('no value - Has %d attributes', $node->hasAttributes() ? count( $node->attributes ) : 0 );

            printf( 'Tag: %s Value: %s <br />', $tagname, $value );
        }
    }
?>
```

Where the file `$xmlfile` has the following content:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <catalog>
       <product description="Cardigan Sweater" product_image="cardigan.jpg">

          <catalog_item gender="Men's">
             <item_number id="fred"></item_number>
             <price>39.95</price>
             <size description="Medium">
                <color_swatch image="red_cardigan.jpg">Red</color_swatch>
                <color_swatch image="red_cardigan.jpg">Burgundy</color_swatch>
             </size>
             <size description="Large">
                <color_swatch image="red_cardigan.jpg">Red</color_swatch>
                <color_swatch image="red_cardigan.jpg">Burgundy</color_swatch>
             </size>
          </catalog_item>

          <catalog_item gender="Men's">
             <item_number>QWZ5675</item_number>
             <price>43.95</price>
             <size description="Medium">
                <color_swatch image="blue_cardigan.jpg">Blue</color_swatch>
                <color_swatch image="black_cardigan.jpg">Black</color_swatch>
             </size>
             <size description="Large">
                <color_swatch image="green_cardigan.jpg">Green</color_swatch>
                <color_swatch image="yellow_cardigan.jpg">Yellow</color_swatch>
             </size>
          </catalog_item>

          <catalog_item gender="Men's">
             <item_number>QWZ2675</item_number>
             <price>21.55</price>
             <size description="Medium">
                <color_swatch image="blue_cardigan.jpg">Blue</color_swatch>
                <color_swatch image="black_cardigan.jpg">Black</color_swatch>
             </size>
             <size description="Large">
                <color_swatch image="green_cardigan.jpg">Green</color_swatch>
                <color_swatch image="yellow_cardigan.jpg">Yellow</color_swatch>
             </size>
          </catalog_item> 


          <catalog_item gender="Women's">
             <item_number>RRX9856</item_number>
             <price>42.50</price>
             <size description="Small">
                <color_swatch image="red_cardigan.jpg">Red</color_swatch>
                <color_swatch image="blue_cardigan.jpg">Navy</color_swatch>
                <color_swatch image="red_cardigan.jpg">Burgundy</color_swatch>
             </size>
             <size description="Medium">
                <color_swatch image="red_cardigan.jpg">Red</color_swatch>
                <color_swatch image="blue_cardigan.jpg">Navy</color_swatch>
                <color_swatch image="red_cardigan.jpg">Burgundy</color_swatch>
                <color_swatch image="black_cardigan.jpg">Black</color_swatch>
             </size>
             <size description="Large">
                <color_swatch image="blue_cardigan.jpg">Navy</color_swatch>
                <color_swatch image="black_cardigan.jpg">Black</color_swatch>
             </size>
             <size description="Extra Large">
                <color_swatch image="red_cardigan.jpg">Burgundy</color_swatch>
                <color_swatch image="black_cardigan.jpg">Black</color_swatch>
             </size>
          </catalog_item>

          <catalog_item gender="Women's">
             <item_number>RRY9456</item_number>
             <price>32.00</price>
             <size description="Small">
                <color_swatch image="red_cardigan.jpg">Red</color_swatch>
                <color_swatch image="blue_cardigan.jpg">Navy</color_swatch>
                <color_swatch image="red_cardigan.jpg">Burgundy</color_swatch>
             </size>
             <size description="Medium">
                <color_swatch image="red_cardigan.jpg">Red</color_swatch>
                <color_swatch image="blue_cardigan.jpg">Navy</color_swatch>
                <color_swatch image="red_cardigan.jpg">Burgundy</color_swatch>
                <color_swatch image="black_cardigan.jpg">Black</color_swatch>
             </size>
             <size description="Large">
                <color_swatch image="blue_cardigan.jpg">Navy</color_swatch>
                <color_swatch image="black_cardigan.jpg">Black</color_swatch>
             </size>
             <size description="Extra Large">
                <color_swatch image="red_cardigan.jpg">Burgundy</color_swatch>
                <color_swatch image="black_cardigan.jpg">Black</color_swatch>
             </size>
          </catalog_item>

       </product>
    </catalog>
```

Will output the following:

```
Tag: item_number Value: no value - Has 1 attributes 
Tag: price Value: 39.95 
Tag: size Value: RedBurgundy 
Tag: color_swatch Value: Red 
Tag: color_swatch Value: Burgundy 
Tag: size Value: RedBurgundy 
Tag: color_swatch Value: Red 
Tag: color_swatch Value: Burgundy
```

---

A slightly modified example of the above that uses a corrected version of the XML ( which is not valid by the way! )

[The corrected source XML](https://pastebin.com/raw/KFBfjWRd)

```
<?php

    function attribs( $node ){
        $tmp=array();
        if( $node->hasAttributes() ) foreach( $node->attributes as $attrib )$tmp[] = $attrib->nodeName.' = '.$attrib->nodeValue;
        return $tmp;
    }


    $xmlfile='c:/wwwroot/xml/so-stack-data.xml';



    $dom=new DOMDocument;
    $dom->preserveWhiteSpace = false;
    $dom->load( $xmlfile );


    $itr = new RecursiveIteratorIterator( new RecursiveDOMIterator( $dom ), RecursiveIteratorIterator::SELF_FIRST );
    foreach( $itr as $node ){

        if( $node->nodeType==XML_ELEMENT_NODE ) {

            $tagname = $node->tagName;
            $count = $node->hasAttributes() ? count( $node->attributes ) : 0;
            $attribs = implode( PHP_EOL, attribs( $node ) );
            $value = !empty( $node->nodeValue ) ? $node->nodeValue : '';
            $parent = isset( $node->parentNode,$node->parentNode->tagName ) ? $node->parentNode->tagName : 'NONE';
            $children = $node->hasChildNodes() ? $node->childNodes->length : 0;




            printf( '
                <div style="max-width:95%%;overflow-wrap:break-word!important;font-family:calibri,verdana; font-size:0.95rem;margin:0 auto 1rem auto;box-sizing:border-box;padding:0.25rem; border:1px dotted rgba(133,133,133,0.5);">
                    <h2 style="color:green;margin:0 0.5rem 0 0;font-size:1rem;">Tag: <span style="font-weight:normal;color:black;">%s</span></h2>
                    <h2 style="color:green;margin:0 0.5rem 0 0;font-size:1rem;">Value: <span style="font-weight:normal;color:black;">%s</span></h2>
                    <h2 style="color:green;margin:0 0.5rem 0 0;font-size:1rem;">Parent: <span style="font-weight:normal;color:black;">%s</span></h2>
                    <h2 style="color:green;margin:0 0.5rem 0 0;font-size:1rem;">Children: <span style="font-weight:normal;color:black;">%d</span></h2>
                    <h2 style="color:green;margin:0 0.5rem 0 0;font-size:1rem;">Attribute count: <span style="font-weight:normal;color:black;">%d</span></h2>
                    <h2 style="color:green;margin:0 0.5rem 0 0;font-size:1rem;">Attributes:</h2><pre>%s</pre>
                </div>', 
                $tagname,
                $value,
                $parent,
                $children,
                $count,
                $attribs
            );
        }

    }

?>
```

Comment: This script works just for one level. I search for a script which retreives all tags for all levels. This script stripes tags for sublevels.

Comment: please explain "works just for one level" and please add the actual XML data rather than a screenshot of the data. The above, as far as I am aware, will drill down through all the child elements of a given node or the entire document so your comment is unclear.

Comment: With levels i mean, nested elements. This script only retreive the tags for the xml. I also want to know the structure of the xml. I have to build a script to convert this xml to html. For this purpose I also need to know the structure.

Comment: Furthermore, this script doesn't always retreive the attribute. For example if a class is used as attribute, this will shown up in the output of this script.

Comment: I have created a recursive function to get all xml levels. However in the end I used XSTL With this technique I transformed the xml to html.